# Blocklayered module disappeared in new cloned shop in multistore mode

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've enabled multistore mode and created a new shop on the basis of old one (agreed to copy all files, options, products, etc.) and set a theme which was basically also a copy of other one.

I've lost some modules and elements in new shop, but I've managed to revive them by updating modules or changing their settings. However, I am unable to restore blocklayered module. I have tried so far:

- in module's config: rebuilding indexes, prices, etc.
- reinstalling module
- rehooking to position, displayLeftColumn in my case
- enabling columns in theme's config

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new filter template in module settings.